# Sum involving Harmonic numbers and binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, harmonic-numbers

Prove that $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}(-1)^{r-1} \, H_{r} \, {}^{n} C_{r} = \frac{1}{n},$$
where ${}^{n}C_{k} = \binom{n}{k}$ and the Harmonic numbers are defined by $$H_{n} = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{j}.$$

**My attempt:**
I opened the summations, and re-combined the series but I am getting the same terms again.

Using integration I was able to resolve the series and it converted into 
integration of $$ \int_{0}^{1} (1-x)^{n-1} \, dx.$$

Comment: yes. the coeeficnet in binomail expansion of $(1+x)^n$

Comment: **Attention delete voters:** The dupe target is a narrower question ("can we prove this using X"). Voting to reopen.

Comment: Now that the question has been reopened, the dupe target is no longer visible, so let me name it explicitly: it's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627557/a-finite-sum-involving-the-binomial-coefficients-and-the-harmonic-numbers .

Answer (score 4):

$$\require{hyperref}
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}H_k\binom{n}{k}
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}H_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}H_k\binom{n-1}{k}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}H_k\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}H_{k-1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag2\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\tag3\\
&=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\frac1n[n\gt0]\qquad\text{( where [...] are Iverson brackets)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k}$
$(2)$: substitute $k\mapsto k-1$ in the right sum
$(3)$: $H_k-H_{k-1}=\frac1k$
$(4)$: $\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\binom{n}{k}$
$(5)$: if $n\gt0$, the sum including $k=0$ would be $-(1-1)^n=0$
$\phantom{\text{(5):}}$ so the sum without $k=0$ is $1$
$\phantom{\text{(5):}}$ if $n=0$, the original sum is empty

See [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Answer (score 4):

Using $$H_{n} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1- t^n}{1-t} \, dt$$ then
\begin{align}
\sum_{r=1}^{n}(-1)^{r-1} \, H_{r} \, \binom{n}{r} &= \int_{0}^{1} \left( \sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \, (1 - t^r) \right)\, \frac{dt}{1-t} \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - (1 - (1-t)^{n})}{1-t} \, dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} (1-t)^{n-1} \, dt\\
&= \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}

Notice that:
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} \, t^r = 1 - \sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^{r} \binom{n}{r} \, t^r = 1 - (1 - t)^n$$
and when $t=0$ this yields, for $n \geq 1$,
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n} (-1)^{r-1} \binom{n}{r} = 1 - \sum_{r=0}^{n} (-1)^{r} \binom{n}{r} = 1 - (1 - 1)^n = 1 - 0^n = 1.$$

Comment: (+1) This is probably the approach the OP mentions.