# Simplify a combinatorial expression

Tags: combinatorics

I came a cross a kind of combinatorial expression in my research. I'm wondering if there is a way to simplify or rewrite it. The expression is pretty simple. So I'm posting it here instead of MO. It is the following.

$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{i=0}^n (-1)^i{n \choose i} {x-i \choose l}, $

where in my case $x,l$ are some positive integers. It's not hard to show when $l< n$, the expression is $0$. But I would like to know about any possible formula for $l\geq n$. I tried to search in some combinatorial identity book. There are a lot of similar expressions, but none of the identities seems to apply. Any idea or answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let $x=m$ and $l=n+j$ & use $\binom{m-i}{n+j} =[y^{n+j}]: (1+y)^{m-i}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
S= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom {m-i}{n+j} = [y^{n+j}]: \sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} (1+y)^{m-i} \\
= [y^{n+j}]: (1+y)^m (1- \frac{1}{1+y})^n \\
=[y^{n+j}]: (1+y)^{m-n} y^n =\binom{m-n}{j}. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Wow! I didn't expect it's that easy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\binom{x-k}{l}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{n-k}\sum_{j=0}^{n-k}\binom{x-n}{l-j}\binom{n-k}{j}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}(-1)^k\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{x-n}{l-j}\binom{n-j}{k}\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{x-n}{l-j}[j=n]\tag{3}\\
&=\binom{x-n}{l-n}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)
$(2)$: change order of summation and $\binom{n}{n-k}\binom{n-k}{j}=\binom{n}{n-j}\binom{n-j}{k}$
$(3)$: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-j}(-1)^k\binom{n-j}{k}=[j=n]$
$(4)$: apply the [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)

Answer (score 2):

Just to show another way to solve it.

The *backward Delta (finite difference)* is defined as
$$
\eqalign{
  & \nabla _{\,x} \,f(x) = f(x) - f(x - 1)  \cr 
  & \nabla _{\,x} ^n \,f(x) = \nabla _{\,x} \,\left( {\nabla _{\,x} ^{n - 1} \,f(x)} \right) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;f(x - k)}  \cr} 
$$

So
$$
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;\left( \matrix{
  x - k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}  = \nabla _{\,x} ^n \,\left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  l \cr}  \right) = \nabla _{\,x} ^n \,{{x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} } } \over {l!}} = {1 \over {l!}}\nabla _{\,x} ^n \,x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} } 
$$
where $x^{\,\underline {\,l\,}} $ is the *Falling Factorial*

It is easy to demonstrate that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \nabla _{\,x} \;x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} }  = x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} }  - \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,l\,} }  = l\left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,l - 1\,} }   \cr 
  & \nabla _{\,x} ^n \,x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} }  = l^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } \left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,l - n\,} }  \cr} 
$$
and therefore
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;\left( \matrix{
  x - k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}  = \nabla _{\,x} ^n \,\left( \matrix{
  x \cr 
  l \cr}  \right) = {1 \over {l!}}\nabla _{\,x} ^n \,x^{\,\underline {\,l\,} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {l!}}l^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } \left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,l - n\,} }  = {1 \over {\left( {l - n} \right)!}}\left( {x - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,l - n\,} }  = \left( \matrix{
  x - n \cr 
  l - n \cr}  \right) \cr} 
$$

which is valid for $x$ integer, but also real or even complex.

By the way, it might be interesting to note that the [Binomial Inversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55659) also assures you that the reverse
of the above is true, i.e.
$$
\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;\left( \matrix{
  x - k \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  x - n \cr 
  l - n \cr}  \right)\quad  \Leftrightarrow \quad \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^k \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\;\left( \matrix{
  x - k \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)}  = \left( \matrix{
  x - n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)
$$

Comment: Interesting technique, using difference operators and falling factorials. I must admit, I did not think the answer would be that simple, so I am grateful for your independent verification.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Glad to have presented another approach. And yes, in situations like this, finite difference might be very helpful and straight.