# $\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m+k}{m-r}$

Tags: combinatorics

Let
$$b_n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m+k}{m-r}$$
By Vandermonde's identity, there has
$$\binom{m+n}{m-r}=\binom{n+m}{n+r}=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{k+r}$$
so $$b_n=\binom{m}{n+r}$$
I wonder if it is possible to directly calculate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m+k}{m-r}$$
to get $$\binom{m}{n+r}$$

Comment: You may look at Binomial inversion formula .. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/combinatorial-interpretation-of-binomial-inversion

Comment: @r9m Yeah,but I have calculated it using the binomial inversion formula, I wonder how to directly calculate it.