# Differential Operator Issue

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, induction, differential-operators

Let us consider the differential operator $H:= x \frac{d}{dx}$ and let us define
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}= \frac{1}{n!}(H+n)(H+n-1)\cdots(H+2)(H+1).
\end{equation}

I proved - by induction - that 
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}\left ( \frac{\log x}{x} \right )=\frac{1}{nx}
\end{equation}

I notice that something similar happens with the following:
\begin{gather*}
\frac{\log(x)}{x^2}; \\
\frac{\log(x)}{x^3}.
\end{gather*}
In particular:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}\left ( \frac{\log x}{x^2} \right )=-\frac{1}{n(n-1)x^2}
\end{equation}
for $n \ge 2$, and
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}\left ( \frac{\log x}{x^3} \right )=\frac{2}{n(n-1)(n-2)x^3}
\end{equation}

So I think that, generally, the following statement is TRUE.

Statement (Conjecture). Let us consider the differential operator $\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}$, then
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}\left ( \frac{\log x}{x^m} \right )=(-1)^{m+1}\frac{(m-1)!}{n(n-1)(n-2) \cdots (n-m+1)x^m}
\end{equation}
with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n \ge m$.

Anyone have any idea how it can be proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show the validity of OPs claim by using some operator calculations and deriving binomial identities. We start with some notational conventions. Here we use *[rising and falling factorial powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Alternate_notations)*
\begin{align*}
x^{\overline{n}}&=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1)\\
x^{\underline{n}}&=x(x-1)\cdots(x-n+1)\\
\end{align*}
 and the differential operator $D_x=\frac{d}{dx}$. Using this notation the operator $\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}$ can be written $$\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}=\frac{1}{n!}(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}$$

We now formulate OPs claim in two steps. At first we transform the operator to a more convenient representation which will be used in the proof below.

> The following is valid
>
> \begin{align*}
> \hat{\mathcal{O}_n}=\frac{1}{n!}(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}
> =\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}x^kD_x^k\qquad &\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and then we apply the operator to $\frac{\log x}{x^m}$
>   \begin{align*}
> \hat{\mathcal{O}_n}\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)&=\frac{1}{n!}(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{mx^m}\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\qquad &\qquad 1\leq m\leq n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

*Approach:* The proof is divided into four steps. At first we derive the operator representation (1). Then we apply (1) to $\frac{\log x}{x^m}$ and derive an expression containing a sum with $x^{-m}\log x$ times a binomial expression  and another sum with $x^{-m}$ times a binomial expression. In step three we show the first binomial sum cancels and in the last step we simplify the other sum to obtain (2).

> **Operator methods:**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \hat{\mathcal{O}_n}&=\frac{1}{n!}(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(xD_x\right)^{\underline{k}}n^{\underline{n-k}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}\left(xD_x\right)^{\underline{k}}\tag{4}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\left[k\atop j\right]\left(xD_x\right)^j\tag{5}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\left[k\atop j\right]\sum_{l=0}^j{j\brace l}x^lD_x^l\tag{6}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}x^kD_x^k\tag{7}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (1) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use the binomial theorem which is also valid for falling factorials. See e.g. exercise 5.37 in *[Concrete Mathematics](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by D.E. Knuth et al.
- In (4) we use the representation of falling factorial powers by *[Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)* $\left[n\atop k\right]$
  \begin{align*}
  x^{\underline{n}}=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]x^j
  \end{align*}
- In (5) we use the representation of $\left(xD_x\right)^n$ by *[Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* ${n\brace k}$
  \begin{align*}
  \left(xD_x\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}{n\brace k}x^kD_x^k
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we use that  Stirling numbers of first and second kind are *[binomial inverse pairs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42018/stirling-numbers-and-inverse-matrices)*.
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\left[n\atop k\right]{k\brace l}=[[n=l]]
  \end{align*}

  with $[[P]]$ the *[Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* notation.

> **Intermezzo:**
>
> According to the transformation (7) of the operator $\hat{\mathcal{O}_n}$ we next calculate up the $k$-th derivative of $\frac{\log x}{x^m}$. We do this by applying the *[general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)*
>
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^k\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)&=\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}D_x^j\left(\log x\right)D_x^{k-j}\left(x^{-m}\right)\\
> &=\log x D_x^k\left(x^{-m}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}D_x^j\left(\log x\right)D_x^{k-j}\left(x^{-m}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> Since 
>   \begin{align*}
> D_x^k\left(x^{-m}\right)&=(-1)^km^{\overline{k}}x^{-m-k}\\
> D_x^k(\log x)&=(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!x^{-k}
> \end{align*}
>   we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> D_x^k\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)&=(-1)^km^{\overline{k}}x^{-m-k}\log x\\
> &\qquad -(-1)^kx^{-m-k}\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}(j-1)!m^{\overline{k-j}}\qquad\qquad m,k\geq 1
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> **Applying the operator:**
>
> Combining the last result with (7) we obtain after some simplifications
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n!}&(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}x^kD_x^k\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)\\
> &=x^{-m}\log x\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}m^{\overline{k}}\\
> &\qquad-x^{-m}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}(j-1)!m^{\overline{k-j}}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

The last steps consist of simplification of both sums in the last expression (8). In fact this simplification provides some nice binomial identities.

> **Cancelling first binomial sum:**
>
> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}m^{\overline{k}}=0\qquad\qquad m,n\geq 1\tag{9}
> \end{align*}
>
> We get
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}m^{\overline{k}}
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{m+k-1}{k}\tag{10}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{-m}{k}\tag{11}\\
> &=\binom{n-m}{n}\\
> &=[[n=m=0]]
> \end{align*}
>   and (9) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (10) we use the upper negation $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (11) we use *[Chu-Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity#Chu.E2.80.93Vandermonde_identity)*.

> **Simplifying second  binomial sum:**
>
> The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-m}{k-j}
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}\frac{1}{j+m}(-1)^{j+m}\binom{n-m}{j}\tag{12}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\binom{n}{m}^{-1} \qquad\qquad1\leq m\leq n\tag{13}
> \end{align*}

We show the identity (12) by application of the Chu-Vandermonde identity. The step from (12) to (13) is a nice identity by its own. We will show it using operator methods.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^n&\binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{1}{j}(-1)^j\binom{-m}{k-j}\tag{14}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n\frac{1}{j}(-1)^j\binom{n}{k}\binom{-m}{k-j}\tag{15}\\
> &=\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}(-1)^{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j}\binom{n}{k+j}\binom{-m}{k}\tag{16}\\
> &=\sum_{j=m}^n\frac{1}{j}(-1)^{j}\binom{n-m}{n-j}\tag{17}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n-m}\frac{1}{m+j}(-1)^{m+j}\binom{n-m}{j}
> \end{align*}
>   and (10) follows.

*Comment:*

- In (14) we exchange the sums.
- In (15) we shift the index $k$ of the inner sum to start from $k=0$.
- In (16) we apply the Chu-Vandermonde identity.
- In (17) we shift the index $j$  to start from $j=0$.

---

Note the *shift operator* $E$ with $E(f(m))=f(m+1)$ and the *delta operator* $\Delta:=E-1$ are related by
\begin{align*}
\Delta^n=(E-1)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{n-j}E^j\tag{17}
\end{align*}

applying the delta operator to $f(m)=\frac{1}{m}$ results in
\begin{align*}
\Delta\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)&=\frac{1}{m+1}-\frac{1}{m}=-\frac{1}{m(m+1)}\\
\Delta^2\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)&=-\frac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)}-\frac{1}{m(m+1)}=\frac{2}{m(m+1)(m+2)}\\
&\cdots\\
\Delta^n\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)&=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{m(m+1)\cdots(m+n)}=\frac{(-1)^n}{m}\binom{m+n}{n}^{-1}\tag{18}
\end{align*}
which can be shown easily by using mathematical induction.

---

> Applying (17) and (18) is essentially the proof of (11) since
>   \begin{align*}
> \Delta^n\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{n-j}E^j\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-1)^{n-j}\frac{1}{m+j}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\binom{m+n}{n}^{-1}
> \end{align*}
>   Replacing $n$ with $n-m$, cancelling $(-1)^n$ and the claim (11) follows.

Finally putting all together

> we obtain from (8), (9) and (13)
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{n!}(xD_x+n)^{\underline{n}}\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{k!}x^kD_x^k\left(\frac{\log x}{x^m}\right)\\
> &=x^{-m}\log x\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}m^{\overline{k}}\\
> &\qquad-x^{-m}\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=1}^k\binom{k}{j}(j-1)!m^{\overline{k-j}}\\
> &=x^{-m}\log x\cdot 0-x^{-m}\cdot\frac{(-1)^m}{m}\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\\
> &=\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{mx^m}\binom{n}{m}^{-1}\qquad \qquad 1\leq m\leq n\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim (2) follows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot many exponents in the question text, but anyway you solve also my mistake. Thank you. I read the answer in this days and I think the proof is correct.

Comment: P.s. I corrected the question text!

Comment: @Nicolò: You're welcome! I think that now both question as well as answer are sound.