# How to prove this sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k-1)}{n-k-1}=\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, catalan-numbers

Let $n\ge 2$ postive integer, show that
$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k(n-k)}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k-1)}{n-k-1}=\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$$

I have done this works
$$I=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k-1)}{n-k-1}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{1}{n-k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k-1)}{n-k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac{2}{k}\binom{2(k-1)}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k-1)}{n-k-1}$$

Comment: Hint: $\dfrac{1}{u}\dbinom{2\left(u-1\right)}{u-1} = 2 \dbinom{2\left(u-1\right)}{u-1} - \dbinom{2u-1}{u-1}$ for each positive integer $u$. Applying this twice allows you to get rid of the denominator in $I$, at the cost of introducing two differences. Expand the product of the differences, and apply the Chu-Vandermonde identity four times. Then simplify.

Comment: @darijgrinberg  Thanks,I have use your hint,I only use two times chu-vandermonde identity,$=4\binom{2n-4}{n-2}-2\binom{2n-3}{n-2}$,wihci wrong? can you post it

Comment: Ah, I meant to apply my argument to the original form of $I$, not to your modified version. The answer doesn't look too bad; you probably made a little typo somewhere.

Comment: @functionsug: There seems to be a typo at the RHS which should be multiplied with $\frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note the *[Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)* are defined as
\begin{align*}
C_{n}&=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}\qquad\quad n\geq 0\\
\end{align*}
with generating function
\begin{align*}
C(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty C_nz^n=\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)
\end{align*}

> The LHS of OPs binomial identity is a *Cauchy-product* of Catalan numbers
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=1}^{n - 1} C_{k-1}C_{n -k-1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since Cauchy products occur when multiplying series we could work with generating functions:
>
> \begin{align*}
> C^2(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_kC_{n-k}\right)z^n\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Let $[z^n]$ denote the coefficient operator.

> We observe with the help of (1) and (2) for $n\geq 2$
>
> \begin{align*}
> [z^{n-2}]C^2(z)&=[z^{n-2}]\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}C_kC_{n-k}\right)z^n\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}C_kC_{n-2-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}C_{k-1}C_{n-1-k}\\
> \end{align*}
>   on the other hand we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^{n-2}]C^2(z)&=[z^{n-2}]\left(\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\right)^2\\
> &=[z^{n-2}]\frac{1}{2z^2}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)-1\\
> &=[z^{n-1}]\frac{1}{2z}\left(1-\sqrt{1-4z}\right)\\
> &=[z^{n-1}]C(z)\\
> &=C_{n-1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\\
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: Happy new year! Is this approach really different from mine? (+1), anyway.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Happy 2017 and thanks for (+1). Sorry, I wasn't aware of your post, which was nearly done at the same time.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Many thanks, Marko! Although I consider *[this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068538/differential-operator-issue/2083478#2083478)* as my answer of today. Maybe you also want to add a contribution? :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is a convolution identity. You may consider that:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^k}{k}\binom{2k-2}{k-1} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}\tag{1}$$
holds as a consequence of the generating function of [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).
 If you square both sides of $(1)$ and consider the coefficient of $x^n$, you get:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k(n-k)}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}\binom{2(n-k)-2}{(n-k)-1} = [x^n]\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2}-x\right) \tag{2}$$
and for $n\geq 2$, the RHS of $(2)$ is just $\color{red}{\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{n}}$, by $(1)$.